# Combining file tests in Zsh

Tags: zsh

What is the most elegant way in zsh to test, whether a file is either a readable regular file?

I understand that I can do something like

```
if [[ -r "$name" && -f "$name" ]]
...
```

But it requires repeating "$name" twice. I know that we can't combine conditions (-rf $name), but maybe some other feature in zsh could be used?

By the way, I considered also something like

```
if ls ${name}(R.) >/dev/null 2>&1
...
```

But in this case, the shell would complain "no matches found", when $name does not fulfil the criterium. Setting NULL_GLOB wouldn't help here either, because it would just replace the pattern with an empty string, and the expression would always be true.

Comment: I cannot help it, I have to ask: why? The first example is perfectly readable, not overly long to write and you are already using a variable, so accidentally giving different paths is not a problem.

Comment: Maybe this is because of my roots in Perl. In very old versions of Perl, it was necessary to write it in a similar way too, and the Perl community complained  about it, until a shortcut was introduced. In Perl, you would write it as `if(-r -f $name)`, so I hoped for some similar simple solution in zsh too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In very new versions of *zsh* (works for 5.0.7, but not 5.0.5) you could do this

```
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB

if [[ -n $name(#qNR.) ]]
...
```

`$name(#qNR.)` matches files with name `$name` that are readable (`R`) and regular (`.`). `N` enables `NULL_GLOB` for this match. That is, if no files match the pattern it does not produce an error but is removed from the argument list. `-n` checks if the match is in fact non-empty. `EXTENDED_GLOB` is needed to enable the `(#q...)` type of extended globbing which in turn is needed because parenthesis usually have a different meaning inside conditional expressions (`[[ ... ]]`).

---

Still, while it is indeed possible to write something up that uses `$name` only once, I would advice against it. It is rather more convoluted than the original solution and thus harder to understand (i.e. needs thinking) for the next guy that reads it (your future self counts as "next guy" after at most half a year). And at least this solution will work only on *zsh* and there only on new versions, while the original would run unaltered on *bash*.

Answer (score 2):

How about make small(?) shell functions as you mentioned?

```sh
tests-raw () {
  setopt localoptions no_ksharrays
  local then="$1"; shift
  local f="${@[-1]}" t=
  local -i ret=0
  set -- "${@[1,-2]}"
  for t in ${@[@]}; do
    if test "$t" "$f"; then
      ret=$?
      "$then"
    else
      return $?
    fi
  done
  return ret
}

and () tests-raw continue "${@[@]}";
or  () tests-raw break "${@[@]}";


# examples
name=/dev/null
if and -r -c "$name"; then
  echo 'Ok, it is a readable+character special file.'
fi
#>> Ok, it is...

and -r -f ~/.zshrc ; echo $? #>> 0
or  -r -d ~/.zshrc ; echo $? #>> 0
and -r -d ~/.zshrc ; echo $? #>> 1
# It could be `and -rd ~/.zshrc` possible.
```

I feel this is somewhat overkill though.

Comment: It *is* overkill, but nevertheless a nice idea for an application where I need this kind of tests frequently.